# new array not appearing after foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code, as you can see I would like to create a new array inside the `foreach`. Even though its adding perfectly fine WITHIN the loop , all seems to be forgotten once the loop is finished.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {

        $result['categories'] = array();
        echo '<pre>';print_r($result);echo '</pre>';
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($results);echo '</pre>';
```

Result of first `print_r`

```
Array
(
    [word_two_id] => 2
    [categories] => Array
        (
        )

)

Array
(
    [word_two_id] => 3
    [categories] => Array
        (
        )

)

Array
(
    [word_two_id] => 5
    [categories] => Array
        (
        )

)

Array
(
    [word_two_id] => 12
    [categories] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Result of second `print_r`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [word_two_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [word_two_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [word_two_id] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [word_two_id] => 12
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, the `foreach` loop operates on a **shallow copy** of the array, meaning that changes to the elements of the array won't propagate outside of that loop.

To pass the array elements *by reference* instead of *by value*, you put an ampersand (`&`) before the name of the element variable, like so:

```
foreach ($results as &$result) {
    $result['categories'] = array();
    echo '<pre>';print_r($result);echo '</pre>';
}
```

This way, any changes to the array elements are instead performed on a *reference* to that element in the original array.

Marc B made a good point [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27604947/2038227) regarding a consequence of using this method. After the `foreach` loop is done and the code continues, the variable `$result` will continue to exist as a reference to the last element in the array. So, you shouldn't reuse the `$result` variable without removing its reference first:

```
unset($result);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is correct I will accept in 10 mins

Answer (score 3):

`$result` in the foreach is going to be overwritten in your loop on every iteration. e.g. every time the loop rolls around, a NEW `$result` is created, destroying any modifications you'd done in the previous iteration.

You need to refer to the original array instead:

```
foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
                     ^^^^^^^
        $results[$key]['categories'] = array();
               ^^^^^^^
```

Note the modifications. You may be tempted to use something like

```
foreach($results as &$result) 
                    ^---
```

which would have worked, but also leave `$result` a reference pointing somewhere inside your `$results` array. Re-using $result for other purposes later on in the code would then be fiddling with your array, leading to very-hard-to-track bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the key too

try this

```
foreach ($results as $key=>$result) {
    $result['categories'] = array();
    $results[$key] = $result;
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($results);echo '</pre>';
```